# Using ViewHolder Pattern with FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: android, firebase

I want to use view holder pattern in my firebase list adapter. The firebase adapter looks a bit different than the ones with converter view because here in populateView method, the view parameter can't be null and always have a value, so I'm looking for the best way to implement the view holder pattern.

Here is my adapter class:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends FirebaseListAdapter<News> {

    public NewsAdapter(Activity activity, Class<News> modelClass, int modelLayout, Query ref) {
           super(activity, modelClass, modelLayout, ref);
    }

    @Override
    protected void populateView(View view, final News news, int i) {

      final Context context = view.getContext();

      final String title = news.getTitle();
      final String photoUrl = news.getPhotoUrl();

      // Create views and assign values
      ImageView ivPhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_news_photo);

      if (photoUrl != null)
        // Load the image using Glide
        Glide.with(context) 
                .load(photoUrl)
                .into(ivPhoto);

      TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_news_title);
      tvTitle.setText(title)
   }
}
```

Comment: obviously something like: 1. check if view has a tag 2. if has - cast it to viewholder 3. if not - create new viewholder and set it as view's tag ... that's it

Comment: This sounds a good way to go about it, but it's not clear where you said cast to a viewholder and where to set the tag. Could you please add an answer with some code? Thank you.

Comment: `1.2. var vh=(ViewHolder)view.getTag(); 3. if(vh==null){ vh=createViewHolder(view); view.setTag(vh);} /*use view holder here*/`

Answer (score 0):

Here is View Holder

```
public class TaskViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView title,desc,points,remaining;
    public ImageView image;
    public ItemClickListener clickListener;
    public TaskViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
        desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_description);
        points = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_point);
        remaining = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_remaining_entries);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_image);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "clicked on task item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        clickListener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition(),false);
    }


}
```

and here is what i'm doing to load data in RecyclerView

```
public void loadData(){  
 database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        tasks = database.getReference("Tasks");
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TaskPOJO, TaskViewHolder>(TaskPOJO.class, R.layout.task_item, TaskViewHolder.class, tasks) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(TaskViewHolder viewHolder, final TaskPOJO model, int position) {


                Log.wtf("TEstScript1", "populateViewHolder: "+model.getTitle() );
                viewHolder.title.setText(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.desc.setText(model.getDescripttion()+"\n");
                viewHolder.remaining.setText(model.getRemaining()+"/"+model.getPoint());
                viewHolder.points.setText("Points "+model.getRemaining());
                Glide.with(viewHolder.title.getContext())
                        .load(model.getImage())
                        .into(viewHolder.image);


                viewHolder.setClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + model.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Intent TaskPOJODetail = new Intent(getActivity(), Main.class);
                        TaskPOJODetail.putExtra("value","detail");
                        TaskPOJODetail.putExtra("taskId",adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                        startActivity(TaskPOJODetail);
                    }
                });

            }
        };
        recyclerViewTasks.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

here is my task_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:id="@+id/task_image"
            android:src="@drawable/test_tast"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"


            />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/task_image"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Title of Task"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:id="@+id/task_title"
                    />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="30/300"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

                        android:id="@+id/task_remaining_entries"
                        />


            </RelativeLayout>

                <me.biubiubiu.justifytext.library.JustifyTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Loren Ipsum is Simply dummy text of the printing and type settin industry. Developers and designers frequently use this\n "
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:id="@+id/task_description"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"

                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Point 2345345"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/task_point"
                    />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can find below example as a reference,

```
public class RecipeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private static final String TAG = RecipeHolder.class.getSimpleName();
    public TextView recipeName;
    public ImageView recipeImage;
    public RecipeHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        recipeName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_name);
        recipeImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_image);
    }
}
```

And create your custom adapter

```
public class RecipeAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RecipeObject, RecipeHolder>{
    private static final String TAG = RecipeAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;
    public RecipeAdapter(Class<RecipeObject> modelClass, int modelLayout, Class<RecipeHolder> viewHolderClass, DatabaseReference ref, Context context) {
        super(modelClass, modelLayout, viewHolderClass, ref);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(RecipeHolder viewHolder, RecipeObject model, int position) {
        viewHolder.recipeName.setText(model.getRecipename());
        Glide.with(context).load(model.getRecipeImageUrl()).into(viewHolder.recipeImage);
    }
}
```

For more reference you can refer [FirebaseRecyclerView Adapter](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-firebaseui-with-custom-firebaserecycleradapter-example-tutorial/)

Comment: I'm not using RecyclerView, so is it ok to extend RecyclerView.ViewHolder? I tried it and it worked but not sure if it's fine to do that.

Comment: You are extending your RecipeAdapter to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and it uses ViewHolder so it is fine to use RecyclerView.Holder. Is it working from your end ? @fullMoon

Comment: Yes your way is working for me, but I'm using FirebaseListAdapter Not FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, so I'm not sure if extending RecyclerView.ViewHolder is an optimal way to go with FirebaseListAdapter.

Comment: Ok got your point. As far I suggest to use RecyclerView as it is advanced then ListView @fullMoon